# GCC left shift overflow

Tags: c, macos, gcc

The following little program is very awkward using GCC version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664) on a Mac.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int x = 1 << 32;
        int y = 32;
        int z = 1 << y;
        printf("x:%d, z: %d\n", x, z);
}
```

The result is `x:0, z: 1`.

Any idea why the values of x and z are different?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you compiling with -Wall?

Comment: gcc gives: "warning: left shift count >= width of type" for the x shift

Comment: I would guess that the compiler pre-computes the `(1 << 32)` expression because it is a constant.

Comment: I finally found the answer. It is because the Intel processor masks the shift count to 5 bits (i.e. takes your shift amount and bitwise ORs it by 31).

Comment: The most common cause of this that I see is ((x << (32-S)) | (x >> S)), when S happens to end up being 0.  Note that either behavior yields the desired results for this calculation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer: the Intel processor masks the shift count to 5 bits (maximum 31). In other words, the shift actually performed is 32 & 31, which is 0 (no change).

The same result appears using gcc on a Linux 32-bit PC.

I assembled a shorter version of this program because I was puzzled by why a left shift of 32 bits should result in a non-zero value at all:

```
int main(){
    int y = 32;
    unsigned int z = 1 << y;
    unsigned int k = 1;
    k <<= y;
    printf("z: %u, k: %u\n", z, k);
}
```

..using the command `gcc -Wall -o a.s -S deleteme.c` (comments are my own)

```
main:
leal    4(%esp), %ecx
andl    $-16, %esp
pushl   -4(%ecx)
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
pushl   %ecx
subl    $36, %esp
movl    $32, -16(%ebp)  ; y = 32
movl    -16(%ebp), %ecx ; 32 in CX register
movl    $1, %eax        ; AX = 1
sall    %cl, %eax       ; AX <<= 32(32)
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp) ; z = AX
movl    $1, -8(%ebp)    ; k = 1
movl    -16(%ebp), %ecx ; CX = y = 32
sall    %cl, -8(%ebp)   ; k <<= CX(32)
movl    -8(%ebp), %eax  ; AX = k
movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
call    printf
addl    $36, %esp
popl    %ecx
popl    %ebp
leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
ret
```

Ok so what does this mean? It's this instruction that puzzles me:

```
sall    %cl, -8(%ebp)   ; k <<= CX(32)
```

Clearly k *is* being shifted left by 32 bits.

You've got me - it's using the `sall` instruction which is an [arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift). I don't know why rotating this by 32 results in the bit re-appearing in the initial position. My initial conjecture would be that the processor is optimised to perform this instruction in one clock cycle - which means that any shift by more than 31 would be regarded as a don't care. But I'm curious to find the answer to this because I would expect that the rotate should result in all bits falling off the left end of the data type.

I found a link to http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/sal.htm which explains that the shift count (in the CL register) is masked to 5 bits. This means that if you tried to shift by 32 bits the actual shift performed would be by zero bits (i.e. no change). There's the answer!

Comment: You are right that the SALL instruction is being used - I noticed that too and checking the Intel Instruction Set Reference reveals this: "However, all other IA-32 processors (starting with the Intel 286 processor) do mask the shift count to 5 bits, resulting in
a maximum count of 31."
So the value of 32 is being ignored - 1 is the unchanged argument, not rotated by 32.

Comment: It should be (32 & 31) for masking.

Comment: The faydoc link is broken.

Answer (score 18):

If your `ints` are 32 bits or shorter, the behaviour is undefined ... and *undefined behaviour cannot be explained*.

The Standard says:

> 6.5.7/3 [...] If the value of the right operand is negative or  is  greater  than  or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

---

You can check your `int` <s>width</s> bit size, for example with:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("bits in an int: %d\n", CHAR_BIT * (int)sizeof (int));
    return 0;
}
```

And you can check your `int` width (there can be padding bits), for example with:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int width = 0;
    int tmp = INT_MAX;
    while (tmp) {
        tmp >>= 1;
        width++;
    }
    printf("width of an int: %d\n", width + 1 /* for the sign bit */);
    return 0;
}
```

*Standard 6.2.6.2/2: For  signed  integer  types, the  bits  of the object representation shall be divided  into  three  groups:  value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit.  There need not be any padding bits; there shall be exactly one sign bit*

Comment: No offence, but that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: "The Standard only allows `x << y` when `(y < sizeof x)`".  This statement is wrong in two ways: the standard *allows* the shift but says the result is undefined.  For a particular compiler on a particular architecture it *may* give predictable results, but doesn't have to.  Also the second part should be `y < widthInBitsOf(x)`

Comment: @pmg I hope you are not serious. Undefined behaviour means that the compiler can do whatever he wants. But it certainly doesn't mean that it can't be explained or that it won't be consistent.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Your assumption is undefined.

Comment: @pmg: `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)` is not necessarily the width of the type, there may be padding bits.

Comment: Undefined behaviour cannot be explained *from the standard*. It is not beyond human ingenuity to investigate the behaviour for a particular compiler and hardware.

Comment: hehehe, thanks Steve. Now I understand why my post keeps getting downvoted. But, imagine the OP compiles the same program now with -O3 optimization and the result is x:0, z: 0. How do you explain the difference? Then he compiles on a Cray and the result is x:4294967296 z: 4294967296 ... ...

Comment: @pmg: same way I would have explained the original behavior - look at the disassembly ;-) Good point, though, any investigation into the behaviour for "a particular compiler and hardware" must take into account that it might vary according to compiler flags, and that on some implementations the behavior is defined by the standard. Others took the question to ask for an account of the specific results, whereas you've explained why the two numbers are *allowed* to be different (or for that matter, it being UB, allowed to be penguins).

Comment: @Steve: Any investigation for UB has to take into account more than the compiler (+options) and hardware: UB doesn't have to be consistent within the same program.  Because it's *beyond the scope of the language to explain,* you have to look at the disassembly.

Comment: @Roger: it doesn't *have* to be consistent, but it is allowed to be. So you don't necessarily have to look at the disassembly, because there's a "scope" in between the scope of the language, and the object code: namely the implementation documentation. In some cases it is sufficient to look at that documentation. Sometimes (not this time), another standard like POSIX, which the implementation purports to also implement, will define behavior which the C standard does not. But as you indicate, the investigation of the behaviour for a particular compiler likely involves examining executables.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be It could, for some compiler/computer/time-of-day combination, usually be explained (sometimes with great effort and usually without much benefit). But I would be very cautious of proclaiming that the results of UB are "consistent".

Comment: Also let us not forget that some outcomes of UB are dependent upon runtime state (e.g. dereferencing a dangling pointer often relies on what object, if any, _now exists_ in the old object's position in memory) and reading the program's assembly isn't going to help you one bit with that one.

Answer (score 7):

The C99 standard says that the result of shifting a number by the width in bits (or more) of the operand is undefined.  Why?

Well this allows compilers to create the most efficient code for a particular architecture.  For instance, the i386 shift instruction uses a five bit wide field for the number of bits to shift a 32 bit operand by.  The C99 standard allows the compiler to simply take the bottom five bits of the shift count and put them in the field.  Clearly this means that a shift of 32 bits (= 100000 in binary) is therefore identical to a shift of 0 and the result will therefore be the left operand unchanged.

A different CPU architecture might use a wider bit field, say 32 bits.  The compiler can still put the shift count directly in the field but this time the result will be 0 because a shift of 32 bits will shift all the bits out of the left operand.

If the C99 defined one or other of these behaviours as correct, either the compiler for Intel has to put special checking in for shift counts that are too big or the compiler for non i386 has to mask the shift count.

The reason why

```
   int x = 1 << 32;
```

and

```
   int z = 1 << y;
```

give different results is because the first calculation is a constant expression and can be performed entirely by the compiler.  The compiler must be calculating constant expressions by using 64 bit arithmetic.  The second expression is calculated by the code generated by the compiler.  Since the type of both y and z is `int` the code generates a calculation using 32 bit wide ints (int is 32 bits on both i386 and x86_64 with gcc on Apple).

Comment: @DonHatch when I said "must" I was speculating about the exact behaviour of the compiler in this instance, I was not saying "the C standard mandates 64 bit arithmetic".  The fact that `(int)(1 << 32)` is zero means that the Intel version of gcc is definitely not using the 32 bit version of the shift to calculate the shift, or if it is, it is doing a check to see if the shift is greater than 31.

Comment: Hey @JeremyP, thanks, that makes sense, thanks for explaining.  I made a suggested edit to change "must calculate" to "must be calculating" which would have avoided my misunderstanding.  I removed my previous comment and my downvote. (actually downvote is locked in at the moment but will be unlocked if the edit gets accepted I think)

Comment: Did you speculate it using 64-bit arithmetic for constant calculation because the bit never overflowed and instead probably kept moving further down a larger bit-space (64 for example). I guess we could test it with: int x = 1 << 64

Comment: Actually `x = 1 << 64` and `x = 0; x |= (1 << 64)` won't tell us anything because we'd push the `1` off the left end anyways and it wouldn't necessarily wrap around/overflow to the lower bits

Answer (score 0):

In my mind "int x = y << 32;" does not make sense if sizeof(int)==4.

But I had a similar issue with:

long y = ...
long x = y << 32;

Where I got a warning "warning: left shift count >= width of type" even though sizeof(long) was 8 on the target in question. I got rid of the warning by doing this instead:

long x = (y << 16) << 16;

And that seemed to work.

On a 64 bit architecture there was no warning. On a 32 bit architecture there was.