#  Does a/the C compiler carry out shift operations at compile time?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bit-shift

It was mentioned that a well written compiler for C should carry out the shift opeators at compile time (i.e. not run-time); for example in this code the shift left - <<.  Can anyone attest to the validity of this?

Code:

```
constant unsigned int elements = length/8 + (length % y > 0 ? 1 : 0);  
unsigned char bit_arr[elements];
```

Psuedo-Code :

```
bit_arr[i] |= (1 << j); // Set 
bit_arr[i] &= ~(1 << j);  // Unset
if( bit_arr[i] & (1 << j) ) // Test
```

Comment: declare one or more of your variables as `const`, then print an assembly language listing and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you actually asking?  Do you mean "will the compiler do the shift itself"?  If that's what you're asking the answer is "it depends" :).  If the number being shifted and the size of the shift are both compile-time constants the compiler almost surely will do the shift (though it doesn't have to).  Otherwise it will generate the lower-level code that will carry out the shift (which will often be a single machine instruction).

Answer (score 3):

Any compiler conforming to the C standard will provide the shift operators `<<` and `>>`, as specified in the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) at §6.5.7. They will work without problems with integer expressions (be them constant or not)<sup>1</sup>).

<s>However, be careful when using them on negative integers, since the sign propagation is not mandated by the standard (actually, left shift with a negative left operand is undefined behavior, while right shift is implementation-defined). Also, overflow behavior with signed integers is undefined.</s>

---

<s>1. As specified at §6.5.7 ¶2, the only constraint on the operands is</s>

> Each of the operands shall have integer type.

---

All this stuff is no longer relevant, since the question changed completely.

For what it's worth, the compiler can, and usually will, perform computations at compile time when all the operands are known (and optimizations are enabled).

Comment: Is everything defined for an positive integer in a signed integer type? Will >> shift in zeros on the high end, for example? Simple answer = don't use signed types for bitvectors, but out of curiosity...

Comment: For `>>`, yes, the behavior is the same as for the `unsigned` types.

For `<<`, instead, it gets tricky on overflow: on `unsigned` types the bits that "exit" from the left are discarded (the standard talks about "modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type."). For positive signed types, instead, the result value has to be representable into the type, otherwise the behavior is undefined. But I agree with you that the rule of thumb is "use shift operators only on `unsigned` types". :)

Answer (score 3):

Compilers are not obligated to translate your program, *verbatim* (or the way you expect) into assembly or machine language.  Compilers have freedom to translate your program as long as the behavior is the same, within the confines of the Language Standard.  If your program invokes undefined behavior, platform specific behavior or behavior defined by the compiler, all bets are off.

Compilers may often not code shifts with constants.  They may calculate the values during compilation and load values instead.  They may choose to multiply or divide rather than shifting.

Smarter compilers may evaluate your expressions and use a more efficient formula to produce the answer.  On the other hand, compilers may also eliminate shifts whose answers are not used.

I suggest concentrating on the correctness and robustness of your program rather than worrying about how the compiler optimizes the code.  After your program is working correctly and is robust, optimize if you have the extra time or if the program's size or execution speed are unsatisfactory.

Comment: That last paragraph is often written as: "first do it, then do it right, then do it fast".

Answer (score 1):

One example of compiler-implemented shifts is the following sample (with undefined behavior):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int i = 32;
    printf("%d %d\n", 1 << 32, 1 << i);
    return 0;
}
```

With gcc 4.3.4 on Cygwin, `gcc foo.c; ./a` gives `0 1` rather than the expected `0 0`.  (**gcc** *does* give a compiler warning, And with `-O3`, you do get the expected result, with two warnings.) For the reason, see SO [GCC left shift overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871650/gcc-left-shift-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Every C compiler has to implement shift operators, as they are part of the language. There aren't any constraints on j.

**EDIT:** Since you changed the question completely: Yes, to be optimized away, of course j needs to be a compile time constant, otherwise, how should the compiler know it's value at compile time, but optimizing arithmetical instructions with constant operands, is one of the first things done, when optimizing the code. Actually, VC and gcc do that even when no optimization level is activated, I think, as it is just obvious.

Comment: Not sure about no constraints on j. For example, if j is larger than the number of bits in the integer type, isn't the result undefined?

Comment: Compilers don't have to *implement* the operations; they have to provide equal functionality.  They can issue multiply instructions instead of shifting.  A program, is just a set of suggestions to a compiler.

Comment: At least there are no constraints that j be a constant or something.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but the result is defined. When they provide equal functionality, they are implementing it. But you're right, it could be, that the microcontroller controling your showerhead does not have a dedicated shift instruction!

Comment: @Christian - unlikely. Some simple processors, you have to implement multiply using shift and add, so no multiply happens - but no shift instruction would be pretty bizarre. You could add a value to itself for a left shift, but I can't think how you'd implement a right shift from other basic instructions. Divide is the more likely omission, with right shifts needed as part of the division algorithm, so "divide by (powers of) two" would be cheating.

Comment: I know, that's why the previous comment was more of a sarcastic character. But let's close on this.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler can determine the value of the operands at compile-time, and it's being invoked at an appropiate optimization level, it will probably do the operation at compile-time.

Marking a variable as `const` may help the compiler do that determination. The compiler may also do it itself in certain cases via data flow analysis (e.g: a local variable initialized to a constant and never modified, ...).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a dependency upon j being a
>   constant vs. being variable?

Of course there is. How can the compiler compute a result at compile time that depends on an operand that isn't known until run time?

Whoever 'mentioned' that to you either is misinformed or didn't say what you understood them to say.