# Why doesn't left bit-shift, "<<", for 32-bit integers work as expected when used more than 32 times?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

When I write the following program and use the GNU C++ compiler, the output is `1` which I think is due to the rotation operation performed by the compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    std::cout << (a << 32) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But logically, as it's said that the bits are lost if they overflow the bit width, the output should be 0. What is happening?

The code is on ideone, http://ideone.com/VPTwj.

Comment: I see output "0" on the linked page; am I missing something?

Comment: yup! 0 http://ideone.com/elyN0

Comment: You might want to show exactly what command line (switches) you have used, what version of GCC and also on which platform.

Comment: @ all I get the output as 1 and it appears as if it is performing the rotation operation

Comment: @xanatos How do you know that this is a "wrong" question?!

Comment: @xanatos its a genuine doubt man I am not here for free points :) simple I have a doubt and I wanna clear it

Comment: if `int` is 32bits isn't it undefined or implementation defined?

Comment: why the close votes? a proper question

Comment: @everyone Because before someone edited the question, he posted a link on ideone? I have reedited the question. Please feel free to check the history!

Comment: @awoodland I too think so. According to latest draft: "The behavior is undefined if the right operand
is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand." (5.8) N3291

Comment: The problem is that, as given by the OP, the question was illogical. He said "look here, it gives me 1", but the example he gave returned 0 :-)

Comment: @AnkitSablok Could you run it with `g++ -S` to show the output?

Comment: @xanatos I see your point, but it is not enough because his code is exhibiting "Undefined Behavior", and in that case you have to check the rules of the language because the compiler is allowed to do anything!

Comment: @AraK No. If he gives us a specific implementation of the compiler (the one of IdeOne), then we can look at the rules used by GCC, and probably discover that on GCC it's defined. He gave a SPECIFIC example on a SPECIFIC compiler. It's different than asking "what shoud I have?"

Comment: @xanatos He didn't provide the version nor the options used to compile the code.

Comment: @Arak Before speaking, at least follow the link and watch the history. His original message was: `when i write the following program on GNU C++ compiler http://ideone.com/VPTwj it shows me an output of 1` then please follow the link and look at the upper left: `language: C++ (gcc-4.3.4)`. I think it's as much clear as it can be.

Comment: @xanatos Duh! I didn't see the link, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the C standard say about bitshifting more bits than the width of type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270492/what-does-the-c-standard-say-about-bitshifting-more-bits-than-the-width-of-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left shift an integer by 32 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058340/left-shift-an-integer-by-32-bits)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCC left shift overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871650/gcc-left-shift-overflow)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is caused due to a combination of an undefined behaviour in C and the fact that code generated for IA-32 processors has a 5 bit mask applied on the shift count. This means that on IA-32 processors, the range of a shift count is **0-31** only. <sup>[1](http://codeyarns.com/2004/12/20/c-shift-operator-mayhem/)</sup>

From *The C programming language* <sup>2</sup>

> The result is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the number of bits in the left expression’s type.

From *IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer’s Manual* <sup>3</sup>

> The 8086 does not mask the shift count. However, all other IA-32 processors (starting with the Intel 286 processor) do mask the shift count to 5 bits, resulting in a maximum count of 31. This masking is done in all operating modes (including the virtual-8086 mode) to reduce the maximum execution time of the instructions.

---

<sup>1</sup>  http://codeyarns.com/2004/12/20/c-shift-operator-mayhem/

<sup>2</sup>  A7.8 Shift Operators, Appendix A. Reference Manual, The C Programming Language

<sup>3</sup> SAL/SAR/SHL/SHR – Shift, Chapter 4. Instruction Set Reference, IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer’s Manual

Comment: Could you please include the essence of that blog post in your answer (cf http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/244745)?

Answer (score 48):

In C++, shift is only well-defined if you shift a value less steps than the size of the type. If `int` is 32 bits, then only 0 to, and including, 31 steps is well-defined.

So, why is this?

If you take a look at the underlying hardware that performs the shift, if it only has to look at the lower five bits of a value (in the 32 bit case), it can be implemented using less logical gates than if it has to inspect every bit of the value.

**Answer to question in comment**

C and C++ are designed to run as fast as possible, on any available hardware. Today, the generated code is simply a ''shift'' instruction, regardless how the underlying hardware handles values outside the specified range. If the languages would have specified how shift should behave, the generated could would have to check that the shift count is in range before performing the shift. Typically, this would yield three instructions (compare, branch, shift). (Admittedly, in this case it would not be necessary as the shift count is known.)

Comment: But... *why* is this undefined behavior? Why couldn't the low-level code perform the subtraction, determine that it need consider only the lowest *zero* bits, and return 0 without inspecting the value at all?

Comment: @Beta - it's undefined so as not to encumber implementations with the burden of emulating in software what was "the norm" in hardware at the point in time when the standard was conceived.

Comment: @Beta: interesting question ! Most of those undefined operations map directly to processor instructions. The behavior is generally *undefined* because doing otherwise would require checks prior to the operations that would not be implemented efficiently on most architectures. Typical safety/speed tradeof.

Comment: @Beta: "Don't pay for what you don't need" principle. **You** can do the check, if your code needs it. But if the check was automatic, you could not _not_ do it.

Comment: @Beta, Imagine the instruction for shift in a certain computer takes 5 bits. No matter what you do, you just can't shift a variable by 32! (Something like 01011 (shift) 010 (to register 2) 110 (from register 6) ????? (shift amount) (This is an imaginary but very possible instruction))

Comment: Nice example of specifications being "optimized" for existing CPUs, but made counter intuitive in process. Damn.

Comment: @MSalters Pascal had a nice alternative to pretty much the same problem - keep everything as defined as possible, *but* give an option to opt-out (using preprocessor directives). It's much more multi-platform friendly.

Answer (score 24):

It's undefined behaviour according to the C++ standard:

> The value of E1 << E2 is E1
>   left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are zero-filled. If E1 has an
>   unsigned type, the value of the result
>   is E1 × 2^E2, reduced modulo one more
>   than the maximum value representable
>   in the result type. Otherwise, if E1
>   has a signed type and non-negative
>   value, and E1×2^E2 is representable in
>   the result type, then that is the
>   resulting value; **otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined**.

Comment: that's some mighty quick standard searching!

Comment: @awoodland Yes, Google is seriously impressive!

Comment: your answer doesnt justify the query sir i am interested in knowing y arent the bits lost and the answer should be 0 as per me but it does some sort of rotation and puts the last bit in the 1st position and u can confirm this with other numbers as well

Comment: Oh I see. I'd fired up a PDF reader and got about as far as the table of contents.

Comment: @AnkitSablok Undefined behavior means that any behavior can happen ;) check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: @Ankit - but it does exactly answer it. That's the beauty of undefined behaviour, *anything* goes!

Comment: @Ankit The answer should not be 0. The answer is undefined. The answer could be anything. This is the essence of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AnkitSablok - it DOES justify the behaviour. The point is that when behaviour is undefined the compiler is allowed to do anything it pleases. At best guess the compiler has simply decided to do nothing (which is perfectly valid according to the standard)

Comment: That's not the best part to quote.  The preceding paragraph states "The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand" so `n << 32` is an UB regardless of the signedness of the left operand

Answer (score 13):

The answers of Lindydancer and 6502 explain why (on some machines) it happens to be a `1` that is being printed (although the behavior of the operation is undefined). I am adding the details in case they aren't obvious.

I am assuming that (like me) you are running the program on an Intel processor. GCC generates these assembly instructions for the shift operation:

```
movl $32, %ecx
sall %cl, %eax
```

On the topic of `sall` and other shift operations, page 624 in the [Instruction Set Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.htm) says:

> The 8086 does not mask the shift count. However, all other Intel Architecture processors
>   (starting with the Intel 286 processor) do mask the shift count to five bits, resulting in a
>   maximum count of 31. This masking is done in all operating modes (including the virtual-8086
>   mode) to reduce the maximum execution time of the instructions.

Since the lower 5 bits of 32 are zero, then `1 << 32` is equivalent to `1 << 0`, which is `1`.

Experimenting with larger numbers, we would predict that

```
cout << (a << 32) << " " << (a << 33) << " " << (a << 34) << "\n";
```

would print `1 2 4`, and indeed that is what is happening on my machine.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't work as expected because you're expecting too much.

In the case of x86 the hardware doesn't care about shift operations where the counter is bigger than the size of the register (see for example SHL instruction description on [x86 reference documentation](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.htm) for an explanation).

The C++ standard didn't want to impose an extra cost by telling what to do in these cases because generated code would have been forced to add extra checks and logic for every parametric shift.

With this freedom implementers of compilers can generate just one assembly instruction without any test or branch.

A more "useful" and "logical" approach would have been for example to have `(x << y)` equivalent to `(x >> -y)` and also the handling of high counters with a logical and consistent behavior.

However this would have required a much slower handling for bit shifting so the choice was to do what the hardware does, leaving to the programmers the need to write their own functions for side cases.

Given that different hardware does different things in these cases what the standard says is basically "Whatever happens when you do strange things just don't blame C++, it's your fault" translated in legalese.

Comment: A bit more precisely, at least in the case of older versions of gcc, a<<b would be implemented as equivalent to a<<(b&31).  I actually relied on this behavior once upon a time in a game, where a>>33 was faster and generated equivalent code to a>>1 (due to some implementation details of the 80486 CPU).  Of course in retrospect I realize how foolish it was to do that, but I was young and inexperienced, and it DID give me a significant speed increase in an often-run inner loop.

Comment: @fluffy: It's not gcc, it's the processor. Given that the standard doesn't require any specific behavior what the guys from gcc did was just to use the assembler instruction for the shift not caring about what to do in case the counter was too big or negative. If you check the manual I pointed to you will see that indeed the x86 family uses the low 5 bits of the counter, ignoring the others... in their words "The count is masked to five bits, which limits the count range
to 0 to 31". The standard wanted to leave this exact freedom, so that shift can become just one asm instruction.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it's a matter of how the code is generated by the compiler.  It was a case of `shr eax` vs. `shr eax,1`, and the fact that gcc had a design facet in which `shr eax,33` would AND the immediate operand with 31 to ensure that it fit into the 5-bit parameter slot in the instruction.  Immediate-mode `shr` has the shift amount encoded *directly in the instruction*, at least on x86 and most other CISC architectures.  i.e. it's a matter of how the compiler is doing the masking TO SUPPORT THE CPU. It's a fine distinction but important.

Comment: @fluffy: The reason for which the standard doesn't mandate a behavior when counter is bigger than the bit size of the value is to avoid a performance penality in case of a **parametric** shift. In case of a constant shift (e.g. 33) a compiler could just simplify to a constant 0 without any performance penality. That gcc decided to keep uniform behavior to the parametric case is a reasonable choice but not the only one (I hope at least a warning was emitted tho). If you need control on the asm instruction generated just use asm... using a non-specified behavior is looking for trouble.

Comment: At the time, gcc didn't emit a warning, but this was in the gcc 2.x days. Nowadays it does emit a warning, which is why I'd even remembered I was doing this terrible thing since I was dusting off old code for nostalgia's sake. :)  And yes, I am fully aware that the behavior was unspecified and that to rely on it is a bad idea. I was just adding more to your answer about one of the particular ways it can behave that is different than the way you were stating. I should have been more precise that I was using immediate-mode >> rather than register-mode >> though.

Answer (score 8):

Shifting a 32 bit variable by 32 or more bits is undefined behavior and may cause the compiler to make daemons fly out of your nose.

Seriously, most of the time the output will be 0 (if `int` is 32 bits or less) since you're shifting the 1 until it drops off again and nothing but 0 is left. But the compiler may optimize it to do whatever it likes.

See the excellent LLVM blog entry [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), a must-read for every C developer.

Comment: IMO it's not the compiler in this case, it's the hardware that doesn't handle shifts bigger than registers. The standard simply didn't want to specify something that would require fatter and slower code for all parametric shifts on some CPUs.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are bit shifting an int by 32 bits; you'll get: `warning C4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior` in VS. This means that you're shifting beyond the integer and the answer could be ANYTHING, because it is undefined behavior.

Comment: It doesn't mean the answer could be 0 or 1, it means that **absolutely anything** could happen

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following. This actually gives the output as `0` after `32` left shifts.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  a <<= 31;
  cout << (a <<= 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* there's a difference between a shift of 32 places, and two shifts that add up to 32 places.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

f = ((long long)1 << (i-1));

Where i can be any integer bigger than 32 bits. The 1 has to be a 64 bit integer for the shifting to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `1LL << 60`. Here `LL` is for `long long`. You can shift now to max of 61 bits.