# bit shifting in C, unexpected result

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

when i pass `n = 0x0`, i get `0xffffffff` on the screen
which i expect should be `0x00000000`
as i shift the word by `32 bits`
(Just Ignore the x! I didn't use it inside the function.)

```
void logicalShift(int x, int n) {
    int y = 32;
    int mask = 0xffffffff;
    printf("mask %x", mask << (y-n));
}
```

One of the interesting point is

```
void logicalShift(int x, int n) {
    int y = 32;
    int mask = 0xffffffff;
    printf("mask %x", mask << 32);
}
```

this will output what i expected. Do i miss out anything? 
Thank you!

Im running on ubuntu

Comment: does making it `unsigned int` change things?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer

Comment: nahh.. i made mask unsigned but it doesn't work as well

Comment: `logicalShift(0xAAAAAAAA, 0);` prints `0` in release and `FFFFFFFF` in debug! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't left bit-shift, "<<", for 32-bit integers work as expected when used more than 32 times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401888/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-for-32-bit-integers-work-as-expected-when-used)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shift left of 32 bits on a 32 bit value has undefined results. You can only shift 0 to 31 bits.

See also here: [Why doesn't left bit-shift, "<<", for 32-bit integers work as expected when used more than 32 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401888/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-for-32-bit-integers-work-as-expected-when-used)

Comment: but the interesting point is when i do the code shown in the lower part, it seems work , it output 0

Comment: @TimothyLeung That's what "undefined results" mean, you can't know what it will be, you're basically lucky it works in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the relevant quote from the [C11 draft §6.5.7.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf);

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or
>   equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned.

In other words, the result is undefined, and the compiler is free to generate any result.

Comment: Your are citing the C++ standard ... there is no C++ in the question, no?

Comment: @JensGustedt Updated with the relevant part of the C11 standard, quoted the C++ standard earlier just because I had it handy.