# c# uint right bit-shift unexpected result

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am confused why does this produce `0xffffffff` in C#, I was expecting it to produce `0x0`. The type of the expression is `uint`.

```
Console.WriteLine(0xffffffff >> 32);
```

Comment: Why did you expect `0x0`?

Comment: because all bits get shifted out to the right and the type is unsigned so should be filled with zeros from the left. the same expression yields 0 in c.

Comment: https://codeyarns.com/2004/12/20/c-shift-operator-mayhem/ tells me c is not perfect on this, too. At least when it comes to shifting 32 bits, also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145636/bit-shifting-an-int-32-times-in-c they call it undefined behaviour.

Comment: btw, why would you need to shift out all of the digits? could you not logically combine it to the max or min value with or/and?

Comment: Interesting Fact: ```Console.WriteLine(0xffffffff >> 31>>1);``` produces 0, as you wished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/right-shift-operator):

> If the first operand is an int or uint (32-bit quantity), the shift
>   count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand
>   (second operand & 0x1f).

The second operand is 32. `32 & 0x1f` is 0. Thus `>> 32` is equivalent to 'shift this by 0 bits' therefore 'do nothing at all'.