# Well-defined bit-shifting more than 32 bits w/o compiler warning

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, template-meta-programming

This is a silly question partly for fun.

I have a "well-defined" (or "saturated"?) bit-mask function

```
template <unsigned N>
uint32_t mask(uint32_t x) {
  const uint32_t MASK = N >= 32 ? ~uint32_t(0) : (uint32_t(1) << N) - 1;
  return x & MASK;
}
```

Expected behavior:

```
uint32_t x = ~uint32_t(0); // 0xFFFFFFFF
mask<8>(x) => 0x000000FF
mask<24>(x) => 0x00FFFFFF
mask<32>(x) => 0xFFFFFFFF
mask<1234>(x) => 0xFFFFFFFF
```

But I don't like to have an undefined code `uint32_t(1) << 1234` within `mask<1234>()` though it is 100% harmless (it shouldn't be evaluated.)  I don't want to see compiler warnings.

- <s>[Why doesn't left bit-shift, "<<", for 32-bit integers work as expected when used more than 32 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401888/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-for-32-bit-integers-work-as-expected-when-used)</s> See my update below

Please suggest me some bit-twiddling tricks (and template meta-programming?) to get rid of `uint32_t(1) << 1234`.

I have GCC 4.9 that (partially) supports C++14 and is smart enough to do constant folding etc

### Update

Quoted from the N4140 draft of the C++14 spec:

5.8 Shift operators [expr.shift]

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand
>   is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

Do you folks have any non-template solution?

Comment: Wait for C++17 or later until you get [`static_if`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3613.pdf).

Comment: There is no warning on newer GCC, it takes the `N >= 32 ?` into account.

Comment: @ElderBug Oops, my whole question might have been irrelevant...

Comment: @ElderBug In fact my actual code involves something like `N >= 8*sizeof(in)` and then GCC cannot see that the bitshift won't be too large.

Comment: Actually the linked question is not really that relevant here. That question is about shifting signed integers, but this is about shifting unsgingned integers. As I interpret the C++ standard left shifting unsigned integers is defined anyway. Maybe this GCC warning is bogus and it's only that which is fixed in newer GCC versions?

Comment: @skyking I checked (drafts of) the C++03 and C++14 specs myself and actually found this statement in the preceding section of one quoted in the above SO post: "The behavior is undefined if the right operand
is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand."  So `uint32_t(1) << 32` certainly causes an UB.

Comment: @nodakai Thank's for pointing that out, I stand corrected. But better to quote that part than referring to the next paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps use partial specialization for that (if the warning bothers you), with inspiration from boost [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html):

```
template <bool, unsigned N>
struct umask32 {
    static const uint32_t val = (uint32_t(1) << N) - 1;
};

template <unsigned N>
struct umask32<true, N> {
    static const uint32_t val = ~uint32_t(0);
};

template <unsigned N>
uint32_t mask(uint32_t x) {
    const uint32_t MASK = umask32<(N >= 32), N>::val;
    return x & MASK;
}
```

If `N>=32` the second `umask32` struct will be used and otherwise the first and consequently avoid the code where you shift by `>=32` bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a version for *admitted* `N`, and another for *not admitted* ones:

```
using my_unsigned = unsigned;

template <my_unsigned N, typename std::enable_if<(N < 8 * sizeof(my_unsigned))>::type* = nullptr >
uint32_t mask(uint32_t x) {
  const uint32_t MASK = (uint32_t(1) << N) - 1;
  return x & MASK;
}

template <my_unsigned N, typename std::enable_if<(N >= 8 * sizeof(my_unsigned))>::type* = nullptr >
uint32_t mask(uint32_t x) {
  return x;
}
```

Thanks to SFINAE, when `N < 2^sizeof(unsigned)`, the first version will be instantiated, otherwise the compiler will pick the (dumb) second version.