# while loop goes infinite when used shift operations in conditon operatios

Tags: c, while-loop, bit-shift

This loop runs infinitely though the value if shift operations becomes zero. Not sure why. Need clarifications.

```
size_t size_of_byte()
 {
  unsigned int size = 0, i = 1; 
  while((i << size) > 0)
   {
     size++;
   }
 printf("The size of a byte is %u",size);

 return size;
}
```

Comment: What language is this?  C?  C++?

Comment: "though the value if shift operations becomes zero." - obviously: not. why don't you print it?

Comment: the value becomes zero, but still the loop is running. Not sure it will check the value or it is checking if the operation is successful :(

Comment: In fact, the debugger will display zero, but the real value used in the assembly code is never less than 1.

Comment: This never becomes 0 hence the while never stops.

Comment: To fix the code you could change to `size = 1; while (i <<= 1) ++size;`. BTW this tells you the size of `unsigned int`, not of byte. And you could use the predefined macro `CHAR_BIT` to find this information out.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401888/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-for-32-bit-integers-work-as-expected-when-used

Comment: `unsigned int != size_t`. And you never change the value of i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking for a betteer link, this is from C++, but the behaviour is the same.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

> if the value of the right operand is negative or is greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand, the behavior
>   is undefined.

The compiler can assume you will never shift more than the width of that integer, consequently, the result will never be 0, so the check is not necessary. This is a perfectly legal optimization, you're relying on UB.

Comment: You are definitely right, but the choice made by, both, `gcc` and `clang` (llvm) are quite strange. If somebody can explain it to me, I would be interested.

Comment: What is wrong with my solution, I ran it and and the output came as 8 which is the size of byte, I am just curious.

Comment: Sir I am confused on part why it has **UB** . Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: @ameyCU: in the code `size` is eventually going to be more (or equal:) than the number of bits, e.g. 32.

Comment: @Dante.: It's UB, anything can happen. The problem will manifest if the compiler *does* the actual optimization (likely case) or if on the platform the result is not 0 (very unlikely).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath  Yeah that explains it  . Thank You Sir !! :)

Comment: Does not this infinite while loop depend on `i = 1`.  Had it been any other value, the loop would stop.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see how your code would ever stop as you are shifting `i` to the **left** by `size` while increasing `size`. This will grow exponentially until overflow occurs and a crash. If I understand you are simply trying to determine the size of a byte with `size_of_byte()`, you are far better served actually checking the number of bits in `1-byte`. By convention, storage for `char` is `1-byte`, so if you wanted to prove to yourself that it really contained 8-bits, you would do something like:

```
/* return the number of bits-per-byte */
size_t szofbyte (void)
{
    unsigned char c = 0;
    unsigned char sz = 1;

    c = ~c; /* invert the bits of c */
    while ((c >>= 1)) sz++;

    return sz;
}
```

It may be instructive to visualize the bit operations involved. Simply adding a few `printf` statements and outputting the value of the variable you are testing in binary will show what is happening and why and how the loop completes as it should. Here is a short example with an annotated version of the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef BITS_PER_LONG
#define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#endif

size_t szofbyte_ann (void);
char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz);

int main (void) {

    printf ("\n the size of a byte is : %zu bits\n\n", szofbyte_ann());

    return 0;
}

/* return the number of bits-per-byte (annotated) */
size_t szofbyte_ann (void)
{
    unsigned char c = 0;
    unsigned char sz = 1;

    c = ~c; /* invert the bits of c */
    printf ("\n sz : %hhu  c : %s\n", sz, binpad (c, 8));
    while ((c >>= 1)) {
        sz++;
        printf (" sz : %hhu  c : %s\n", sz, binpad (c, 8));
    }

    return sz;
}

/* return binary representation of 'n' paddded to 'sz' chars */
char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *--p = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./szofbyte

 sz : 1  c : 11111111
 sz : 2  c : 01111111
 sz : 3  c : 00111111
 sz : 4  c : 00011111
 sz : 5  c : 00001111
 sz : 6  c : 00000111
 sz : 7  c : 00000011
 sz : 8  c : 00000001

 the size of a byte is : 8 bits
```