# Left shift bits in c

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have been making some stupid test about bits manipulation, and I found this issue. I execute this code:

```
int main(){
  unsigned int i;
  for (i=1; i<34; i++)
  {
    unsigned long temp = i;
    unsigned long mul = 1;
    unsigned long val;
    unsigned long one = 1;

    // Way 1
    while (temp--)
      mul = mul << one;

    // Way 2
    val = (one<<i);

    printf(" \n 1<<%i \n mul: 0x%X , val: 0x%X\n",i, mul, val); 
  }
}
```

Of course, I know that when i>31, an overflow will be produced. I think that both parts of code (way1 and way2) should output the same result. But I get this (at the end):

```
 /* ... correct results from i=1 to i=31 ... */
 1<<30 
 mul: 0x40000000 , val: 0x40000000 

 1<<31 
 mul: 0x80000000 , val: 0x80000000 

 1<<32 
 mul: **0x0** , val: **0x1** 

 1<<33 
 mul: **0x0** , val: **0x2**
```

Why, if both instructions are left shifts, the program produces different outputs? It seems that the part way2 produces a round shift, but I don't know why, I really think that "mul" gets always the correct value.

I compile under a Intel 32bits machine, gcc version 4.4.7

Comment: The result of a shift operations with a shift amount larger than the operands width is undefined per C standard.

Comment: Just an opinion, but I'd say that in these cases: `mul << one` and `one<<i`, it's actually better to simply use `1` than giving it the name `one`.

Comment: That's the problem, yes. In this case, it probably ANDs the right operand with 0x3F before doing the shft.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The main problem with that is that `one` is a variable, not a constant.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It's not just the result that's undefined. The *behavior* is undefined. And a shift with a right operand greater than *or equal to* the width of the left operand's type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't left bit-shift, "<<", for 32-bit integers work as expected when used more than 32 times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401888/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-for-32-bit-integers-work-as-expected-when-used)

Comment: In addition to the UB for the shift, your `printf` also invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of

```
val = (one<<i);
```

when `i` gets greater than or equal to 32, the behavior is undefined.

However, in case of

```
while (temp--)
   mul = mul << one;
```

for shifts more than 32, it will shift zero and the result is defined (zero).

Comment: Yes. I think you are right. With the answer of Aif I think it is clear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Probably because that's undefined behaviour? According to `§6.5.7`:

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Well, I could expect some of both behavior, but only one of them in both cases. Don't you think that both operations are equal? EDIT: I see the deepmax answer and I understand you now. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexi Do you understand the meaning of something being undefined?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, my problem was that I understood the "undefined behavior" meaning, but I didn't know why there were two diferents "undefined behavior" whith the (aparently) same operation.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
val = (one<<i);
```

You're doing a single left shift by `i`.  If `i` is greater than 31, this results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning the result may or may not be what you expect.

From section 6.5.7.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  The
>   type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.  **If  the
>   value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or is greater than or
>   equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

However, when you do this:

```
while (temp--)
  mul = mul << one;
```

You're doing a left shift by 1 `i` times.  This is well defined, so it gives you the value you expect.

Also, you're using `%X` to print a `long` when you should be using `%lX`.  This causes undefined behavior as well.

Answer (score -3):

When I compile Your code with `-Wall` I got complaints:

```
BASH> gcc -Wall left-shift.c 
left-shift.c: In function ‘main’:
left-shift.c:21:12: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf(" \n 1<<%i \n mul: 0x%X , val: 0x%X\n",i, mul, val); 
            ^
left-shift.c:21:12: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
```

So I changed printf to

```
printf(" \n 1<<%i \n mul: 0x%lX , val: 0x%lX\n",i, mul, val);
```

With this change "mul" and "val" shows the same results:

```
 1<<30 
 mul: 0x40000000 , val: 0x40000000

 1<<31 
 mul: 0x80000000 , val: 0x80000000

 1<<32 
 mul: 0x100000000 , val: 0x100000000

 1<<33 
 mul: 0x200000000 , val: 0x200000000
```

System information:

```
BASH> gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
BASH> uname -a
Linux bm-pc-ubuntu 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
BASH> lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: This is because your machine is 64-bit and his is 32-bit.

Comment: Ignoring this warning, gives me even strnager output than the original ones:
 1<<30 
 mul: 0x40000000 , val: 0x40000000
 
 1<<31 
 mul: 0x80000000 , val: 0x80000000
 
 1<<32 
 mul: 0x0 , val: 0x0
 
 1<<33 
 mul: 0x0 , val: 0x0

Comment: You should not ignore the warning. If you want to see results similar to the OP, try increasing the loop counter to 66.

Comment: This is awesome... even if absolut logical! Is there a gcc switch to "warn about undefined behaviours"?

Comment: @s7amuser: The wrong type-specifier invokes UB even on a 32 bit machine, where `int` and `long` have the same width.

Comment: @bsmr: You already got warnings for detected UB. But how should the compiler be able to warn about UB at run-time without solving the Halting Problem?

Comment: @Olaf I don't see how your comment relates to my comment. I didn't suggest ignoring the warning.

Comment: @s7amuser: Your comment invokes the impression the reason for the warnings is the machine OP works on (64 vs. 32 here). That is wrong. It should warn even if  both types have the same representation/range, as that UBN is not dependent on the representation, but the type.

Comment: @Olaf Again, *I didn't suggest ignoring the warning* and *I didn't say the warning is because the machine word size* (this is only your wrong interpretation). The reason the OP *gets different results* is because the machine word size. The warning is *not* dependent on the machine word size. I hope everything is clear now.