# C left shift on 64 bits fail

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-shift

I have this code in C (it's for study only):

```
    char x;
    uint64_t total = 0;

    for(x = 20; x < 30; x++){
        total = (((((1 << x) * x) / 64) + 1) * sizeof(uint64_t));
        printf("%d - %llu\n", x, total);        
    }
```

What is printed:

```
20 - 2621448
21 - 5505032
22 - 11534344
23 - 24117256
24 - 50331656
25 - 104857608
26 - 218103816
27 - 18446744073625665544
28 - 18446744073575333896
29 - 18446744073508225032
```

Why at x > 26 do I have those strange values? I'm at gcc 4.6.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 64 bits.

Comment: looks like the problem is at char x, I used uint64_t for it and works good.

Comment: You will be able to see what is happening more clearly if `total = (((((1 << x) * x) / 64) + 1) * sizeof(uint64_t));` is simplified to `total = ((1 << x) * x);` then printed with `printf("%d - 0x%llx\n", x, total);` you will see the the sign bit turning the nmber negative, which is printed as a huge number by printf("... - %llu\n", ... total);

Comment: duplicates: [GCC left shift overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3871650/995714), [how to use uint64_t in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43060408/995714), [What does the C standard say about bitshifting more bits than the width of type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270492/995714), [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because `1` is an `int`, 32 bits, so `(1 << 27)*27` overflows. Use `1ull`.

Regarding your comment, if `x` is a `uint64_t`, then `1 << x` is still an `int`, but for the multiplication it would be cast to `uint64_t`, so there'd be no overflow. However, if `x >= 31`, `1 << x` would be undefined behaviour (as the resulting value cannot be represented by a signed 32 bit integer type).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is, you calculate with 32bit and assign it later to a 64 bit value

division by 64 is the same as not shift 6 bit

```
char x;
uint64_t one = 1;
uint64_t total = 0;

for(x = 20; x < 30; x++){
    total = ((((one << (x - 6)) * x) + 1) * sizeof(uint64_t));
    printf("%d - %llu\n", x, total);        
}
```

not compiled yet