# Why doesn't left bit shift << shift beyond 31 for long int datatype?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I want to use the following code in my program but gcc won't allow me to left shift my 1 beyond 31.

`sizeof(long int)` displays 8, so doesn't that mean I can left shift till 63?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long int x;
    x=(~0 & ~(1<<63));
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiling outputs the following warning:

```
left shift `count >= width` of type [enabled by default] `x=(~0 & ~(1<<63))`;
                                                                    ^
```

and the output is -1. Had I left shifted 31 bits I get 2147483647 as expected of int.

I am expecting all bits except the **MSB** to be turned on thus displaying the maximum value the datatype can hold.

Comment: `#include <limits>` and  `std::numeric_limits<long int>::max()`  ? You are assuming you know how the implementation is storing signed integers. That is not portable. Also char is not guaranteed to be 8 bits.

Comment: @tim-seguine: underrated comment.

Comment: [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714), [left shift on 64 bits fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048047/995714), [how to use uint64_t in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43060408/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although your `x` is of type `long int`, the `1` is not. `1` is an `int`, so `1<<63` is indeed undefined.

Try `(static_cast<long int>(1) << 63)`, or `1L << 63` as suggested by Wojtek.

Comment: Why not `1L` instead of the cast?

Comment: This is still undefined behaviour if `long` is 64-btw (integer overflow).

Comment: Isn't `long` practically always 32 bit?

Comment: @FredOverflow long is 64 bits on (most) Linux/Unix

Answer (score 3):

You can't use 1 (int by default) to shift it beyond the int boundaries.

There's an easier way to get the "all bits except the MSB turned on" for a specific datatype

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned long int max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long int>::max();
    unsigned long int max_without_MSB = max >> 1;
    cout<< max_without_MSB <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

note the unsigned type. Without `numeric_limits`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long int max = -1;
    unsigned long int max_without_MSB = ((unsigned long int)max) >> 1;
    cout << max_without_MSB << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this depend on data representation? (two's complement vs one's complement?)

Comment: `numeric_limits` was in C++98

Comment: Matt is correct, I'll fix that. And this should work for one's complement as well

Comment: @MarcoA. Anyway, this approach is like building a house using a house: You're using `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long int>::max()` to construct `std::numeric_limits<long int>::max()`. That's rather useless.

Comment: @stefan I think the issue is that *technically* signed integral types can have padding bits so `LONG_MAX` might be smaller than you think, although I don't know of any systems that C++ is used on where that actually happens

Comment: @stefan I did it primarily for clarity purposes, but I agree under normal circumstances

Comment: In the first example `max` is all-bits-one so there is not much point doing `&` on it, just `max >> 1` is fine :)

Answer (score 2):

First let me state a few things about the shift, which is the source of your problem:

There is no guarantee that `long int` is actually 64 bit wide.

The most generic way I can think of is using `std::numeric_limits`:

```
static_cast<long int>(1) << (std::numeric_limits<long int>::digits - 1);
```

Now you can even make that a constexpr templated function:

```
template <typename Integer>
constexpr Integer foo()
{
    return static_cast<Integer>(1) << (std::numeric_limits<Integer>::digits - 1);
}
```

---

So replacing the shift with `static_cast<long int>(1) << (std::numeric_limits<long int>::digits - 1)` will fix your issue, however there is a far better way:

`std::numeric_limits` includes a bunch of useful stuff, including:

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); // the maximum value T can hold
std::numeric_limits<T>::min(); // the minimum value T can hold
std::numeric_limits<T>::digits; // the number of binary digits
std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed(); // well, do I have to explain? ;-)
```

See [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) for a complete list. You should prefer the facilities provided by the standard library, because it will most likely have fewer mistakes and other developers immediately know it.

Answer (score 2):

Your title is misleading; a `long` can shift beyond `31` bits if a `long` is indeed that big. However your code shifts `1`, which is an `int`.

In C++, the type of an expression is determined by the expression itself. An expression `XXXXX` has the same type regardless; if you later go `double foo = XXXXX;` it doesn't mean `XXXXX` is a double - it means a conversion happens from whatever `XXXXX` was, to `double`.

If you want to left-shift a long, then do that explicitly, e.g. `1L << 32`, or `((long)1) << 32`. Note that the size of `long` varies between platforms, so if you don't want your code to break when run on a different system then you'll have to take further measures, such as using fixed-width types, or shifting by `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(long) - 1`.

There is another issue with your intended code: `1L << 63` causes undefined behaviour if `long` is 64-bit or less. This is because of signed integer overflow; left-shift is defined the same as repeated multiplication of two, so attempting to "shift into the sign bit" causes an overflow.

To fix this, use unsigned types where it is fine to shift into the MSB, e.g. `1ul << 63`.

Technically there is another issue in that `~0` doesn't do what you want if you are not on a 2's complement system, but these days it's pretty safe to ignore that case.

Looking at your overall intention with `long x = ~0 & ~(1 << 63)`. A shorter way to write this is:

```
long x = LONG_MAX;
```

which is defined by `<climits>`.  If you wanted 64-bit on all platforms then

```
int64_t x = INT64_MAX;
```

NB. If you do not intend to work with negative values then use `unsigned long x` and `uint64_t` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The default datatype for a numeric value in C is integer unless explicitly mentioned.

Here you have to type cast the 1 as **long int** which would otherwise be an int.