# how to use uint64_t in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(){
    uint64_t a = 1 << 63;
    /* do some thing */
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 test.c -o test  
warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
```

Q: `uint64_t` should have 64 bits width,  why the left shift operation overflows?

Comment: 1 is an `int` literal. Using `1ULL << 63` instead

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc  C specifies `1` as an _integer constant_ of type `int`.  The only _literals_ specified in C are _string literals_ and _compound literals_.  `1` is neither of those 2 literals.

Comment: "why the left shift operation overflows?" --> which happens first:  `1 << 63` or its assignment to `uint64_t a`?  Since  `1 << 63` occurs first, the type it is assigned to is irrelevant to  `1 << 63` evaluation.

Answer (score 11):

`1` is an `int` which is either only 32 bits on your platform, or it could be 64 bits but signed.

Use `(uint64_t)1 << 63` to cast `1` to 64-bit unsigned integer first. (Or `((uint64_t)1) << 63` if you prefer)

Comment: no need to cast, `1ULL` looks better. And `(uint64_t)1 << 64` invokes undefined behavior because you shifted more than the value's bit length

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Fixed, 64 should've been 63.