# Can't bitshift a char more than 32 bits into unsigned long long

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bit-shift

I'm trying to bit shift char values into an unsigned long long (or an uint64_t, or an __int64), and whenever I try to bit shift by values greater than 32, it appears to subtract 32 from the size of the bit shift.

Other questions listed here a duplicates don't immediately state that a `char` will be upgraded to only an `int` instead of an `unsigned long long`. Because this was not apparent to me, I didn't know that the rule of not shifting a bit-shifting a value by longer that its size was relevant.

The comments pointed out that the `char` only becomes an `int` and therefore can't isn't upgraded to a 64-bit int before assignment.

### Code

---

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


int main(...)
{

    std::string text = "Saturday 2019-08 August-31__08:46:32.38948-pm Pacific Daylight time-phoneid:xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx";
    //unsigned int val1, val2, val3;
    //val1 = val2 = val3 = 0;

    //val1 = 't';
    //val1 = val1 << 24;
    //std::cout << val1 << std::endl;


    //unsigned long long hash[12];

    //uint8_t hash_count = 0;
    //uint8_t shift_offset = 7;
    //uint8_t hash_iter = 0;
    for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < text.size(); ii+=8)
    {
        unsigned long long test_01 = text[ii] << 56   ;
        unsigned long long test_02 = text[ii+1] << 48 ;
        unsigned long long test_03 = text[ii+2] << 40 ;
        unsigned long long test_04 = text[ii+3] << 32 ;
        unsigned long long test_05 = text[ii+4] << 24 ;
        unsigned long long test_06 = text[ii+5] << 16 ;
        unsigned long long test_07 = text[ii+6] << 8  ;
        unsigned long long test_08 = text[ii+7] << 0;


        //hash_iter++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

### How do I know it's not working?

I'm looking at the values inside the memory window in Visual Studio

### System

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2015
Compile Configuration: Debug, x64

Comment: E.g. `text[ii]` is a single `char`, which might or might not be signed. If you want to shift it more than 7 bits you need to convert it to a 64-bit type first like `static_cast<uint64_t>(text[ii])`. And remember, the assignment to the variable `test_01` is done *after* the 8-bit integers are shifted lots of bits.

Comment: `char` will be promoted to int, and since `int` is a 32-bit type in this case, shifting it more than 31 invokes undefined behavior. [C left shift on 64 bits fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048047/995714), [how to use uint64_t in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43060408/995714), [What does the C standard say about bitshifting more bits than the width of type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270492/995714)

Comment: Whatever is at the left side of the `=` does not influence what happens at the right side. There is no `unsigned long long` at the right side.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude... I am able to shift the `char` up to 24 bits.

Comment: @phuclv... please see that I'm dealing with `unsigned long long`

Comment: @Andrew please read the links I commented. `text[ii]` is a char and not long long. Clearly shifting it left 24 bit works because char here contains only 8 bits

Comment: @phuclv... Roger that... I see them now.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text[ii]` is a single char which will be promoted to `int` to perform binary operation. It is not possible to shift a bit more then the width.

You can easily detect it with compiler warning: [Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2cOZhIJKKIpY6v0o)

To solve the problem you can simply cast the type:

```
char a='a';
uint64_t x = (uint64_t)a<<45;
```

Comment: your edit with example code made this a relevant answer and is now accepted. Thank you

Comment: @Andrew I shared a wrong link in my previous edit. I was checking if he compiler distinguishes the type of a temporary literal correctly and forget to edit the type :)