# Why bitwise operator produce error in calculating the maximum range possible using same number of bits as provided in an integer

Tags: c++

Why is this code not giving expected value for `n = 1000000000000` Expected `value = 1099511627775`
While the code is giving 255

```
long long now = n, count = 0, len = 0;
while (now >= 1) {
  count++;
  now /= 2;
}
len = (1 << count) - 1;
cout << len;
```

Comment: Switch to `unsigned` types, get this working in two flicks of the wrist, then head off to the pub.

Comment: Are you sure you don't cause overflow?

Comment: Your code generates C26451 warning. It's the cause of your problem

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117934/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-shift-beyond-31-for-long-int-datatype) is a near duplicate, although the types used are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't left bit shift << shift beyond 31 for long int datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117934/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-shift-beyond-31-for-long-int-datatype)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `1 << count` the constant `1` is an `int` not a `long long`.
Then the shift overflows.
You should use `1ll << count`.