# Why do 1ll << i does give us correct answer but not long long i ; 1<<i?

Tags: c++, c++11, bitwise-operators

Since 1 operand in `<<` operator is of `long long` type, and the answer should be stored as `long long`,
I am a little surprised by this behavior can anyone explain why this happens?
For Example:

```
   #include<bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;

   int main(){
       long long p=33;
       long long a = 1<<p;
       cout<<a;

   }   //This gives the wrong output
   
    int main(){

       long long a = 1ll<<33;
       cout<<a;

    } //this gives right output
```

Comment: You can include some example in your question to make it better to understand.

Comment: A [mcve] would definitely help to explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't left bit shift << shift beyond 31 for long int datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117934/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-shift-beyond-31-for-long-int-datatype)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 (N3690) 5.8 Shift operators [expr.shift] p1:

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed.
> The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

So the type of `1 << i` is `int`, whereas `1LL << i` has type `long long`, which can usually represent a greater range of values.

The shift operators are exceptional here; most other operators follow the *usual arithmetic conversions* [5 p10], which cause both operands to be converted to the same type, roughly speaking the larger of the two.

Comment: so is there any other exception other than shift operators

Comment: I can't think of any off the top of my head, but you can read through the standard as easily as I can.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic would also be an exception, I think.