# How come I get a big int when I bitwise shift 1 << 45

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, shift

Why do I get such a big int?

```
int ans = 1 << 45;
printf("Check: %d", ans);
return 0;
```

Check: 1858443624

Comment: 1858443624 isn't even a power of two .. I have no idea what happened here.

Comment: I'm just running in xcode, using C

Comment: Why 90? That doesn't make sense either..

Comment: Integer overflow. Undefined behavior.

Comment: it would be 90 if you did `45 << 1`

Comment: @jsn, Not even just integer overflow. Shifting it more than the width of an int is UB.

Comment: @chris Yes, you are right. The undefined behaivor of the improper bit shifting policies catches this case first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is undefined behavior in C. Anything can happen, including stuff like processor exceptions, or unpredictable changes in other parts of the program (which can happen as a side effect of aggressive compiler optimizations).

> 6.5.7/3 [...] If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871650/gcc-left-shift-overflow)

Comment: @ecatmur read the paragraph again, even if the promoted left operand is unsigned *If the value of the right operand [...] is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @ouah oops, so it is, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C standard

> An expression is shifted by a negative number or by an amount greater than or equal to the width of the promoted expression (6.5.7).

is undefined behavior, so the compiler is free to do anything for the code you give here.

Answer (score 2):

90? No way. You need to read what [bit-shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) does. `1<<45`  is essentially `2^45`.  Besides, `int` is only 31 bits (excluding the sign bit), so by trying to shift 45 bits, you're causing undefined behavior.

Quick example:

```
1 << 0  =  1  = 0x01  = 00000001b
1 << 1  =  2  = 0x02  = 00000010b
1 << 2  =  4  = 0x04  = 00000100b
1 << 3  =  8  = 0x08  = 00001000b
```

Comment: Thank you :), i must be confused what bit-shifting does.

Comment: Ahhhh, so 45 < 1, actually results to 90.

Comment: I do not think it is correct to refer to the high-bit of a two's complement integer as a sign bit. It confused me for a number of years until I learned about one's complement and IEEE-754 ..

Comment: @AustinTruong Yes, `45<<1 == 45*pow(2,1) == 90`.

Comment: @pst What platform are you on that uses ones' compliment? And IEEE-754 is floating point - that has nothing to do with this at all. The MSB certainly *is* the sign bit.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My point is two's complement is *not* one's complement and thus it is *not* accurate/precise to say "sign bit" (IEEE-754, like one's complement, has a true sign bit): ["The left-most bit, also called the most-significant bit (MSB), determines the sign of the number, but, unlike the sign-and-magnitude representation, also has a weight, −2m−1, as shown in the formula above. *Because of this weight, it is misleading to call this bit the "sign bit"*."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Comment: @pst However, if you Ctrl+F you'll see 14 other instances where they *do* call it the sign bit. I understand 0x10000000 (DWORD) isn't -0.

Comment: @pst The C standard uses the term "sign bit" too. In all three integer representations, two's complement, ones complement and sign-and-magnitude, it indicates the sign of the number (well, unless it's a trap representation).

Answer (score 1):

clang (as used in X-Code; AFAIK they don't use gcc anymore) is funny with this:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ clang Test.c -Wno-shift-count-overflow; ./a.out
Check: -1344872728
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ clang Test.c -Wno-shift-count-overflow; ./a.out
Check: -1066238232
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ clang Test.c -Wno-shift-count-overflow; ./a.out
Check: -1373126936
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ clang Test.c -Wno-shift-count-overflow; ./a.out
Check: 779153128
```

Apparently, they randomize the result :-)

Comment: It's probably not bothering to initialize the variable at all, so you're seeing uninitialized stack memory.

Answer (score 0):

1) As everybody has already said, the answer is "undefined behavior".

2) In practice, just about every compiler I'm familiar with will give you "0".

3) In practice, most self-respecting compilers will also give you a warning:

```
x.cpp: In function `int main (int, char **)':
x.cpp:7: warning: left shift count >= width of type
```

Comment: "In practice, just about every compiler I'm familiar with will give you "0"."  Put the 45 in a variable and you get 8192 on this Core 2 system (i.e. 1 << 13, the processors ignore the high order bits).