# what values are allowed for the shift count operation?

Tags: c, bit-shift

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int var=1;
    var = var<<32;
    printf("%u ",var);
}
```

This code yield `1` as its output. if i write  `var = var<<31;` it yields `2147483648`.

if i type `var = 12;` and then `var = var<<32;` it yields `12`. I read from my textbook, an old one, that ANSI C does not allow to shift all the bits out of a value in a single operation.

Do all major compilers behave the same(copy paste input to output) or just the GCC does copy paste 12 from input to output when i instruct it to do `var = var<<32;` ???

Comment: Shifting more bits than the number of bits in the data-type leads to *undefined behavior*. So shifting a 32-bit variable by 32 (or more) bits is invalid.

Comment: @Badda That's not a meaningful duplicate, since C has a lot of language-specific behavior when it comes to bit shifts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC left shift overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871650/gcc-left-shift-overflow)

Comment: It is undefined behavior because `32` is outside the range [0 - 31].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C11 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or
>   equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Meaning that there is no well-defined behavior if you shift 32 or more bits in this case. Anything could happen, including crashes and strange results.

> I read from my textbook, an old one, that ANSI C does not allow to shift all the bits out of a value in a single operation.

This is correct, you would have to do several bit operations, for example `x<<=16; x<<=16;` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: if i type `var = 12;` and then `var = var<<32;` GCC outputs `12`.  Will other major compilers give the same output or is it totally undefined **regardless** the compiler? I get the idea that GCC is programmed to give 12 if i try to shift too many bits.

Comment: @Mynicks It is completely undefined, even on the same compiler. GCC might output 12 today, 42 tomorrow and crash & burn the day after. The key here is that you cannot rely on undefined behavior to give a certain kind of behavior... hence undefined.

Comment: @Mynicks, if something is _undefined behaviour_ in C, then it is always and everywhere undefined. GCC seems to just skip the whole shift operation as the result is undefined (a.k.a useless) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

GCC literally says you answer:
`left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]`.

Also it dependce on the architecture you using. And your question have been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871650/gcc-left-shift-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Just for a little more depth:

Classically the C language developed as a "portable assembler." The built-in operations are simply the ones implemented by most CPUs, and their semantics provide a lowest common denominator for portability.

Almost every CPU provides shift-left and -right operations. But platforms differ about details such as overflow and negative numbers, so the C standard leaves corner cases undefined.

In particular, for shift counts greater than the register width, many CPUs only use as many bits as needed and truncate the rest. When the count is a constant, the compiler may note the undefined behavior and simply discard the operation as garbage.