# Are leftshift operators dependent on register size?

Tags: c, 8-bit

Let uint8 and uint16 be datatypes for 8bit and 16bit positive integers.

```
uint8 a = 1;
uint16 b = a << 8;
```

I tested this program on 32Bit architecture with result

> b = 256

Would the same programm on a system with registers of 8bit length yield the result:

> b = 0 ?

because all bits in register gets shifted to 0 by a << 8?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your objective in shifting bits past the end of their size? This seems slightly unusual and may be undefined behaviour.

Comment: The behavior depends on the size of the data types.  Integer operands are promoted to potentially larger integers when used in expressions.  The promoted sizes determine the behavior of the shift operations.

Answer (score 3):

Registers are irrelevant. This is about the width of your types.

When you shift a value by more bits than it possesses, the behaviour is undefined. The compiler, the program, the computer, the tax office can legally manifest any results accordingly. And, no, [that's not just theoretical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3871650/560648).

However, [operands in C are *promoted* before interesting things are done on them](https://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/promo_conv.html). So, your `uint8_t` becomes an `int` before the left-shift.

*Now* it depends on your architecture (as determined by your compiler configuration) as to what happens: is `int` on your implementation only 8-bit? [No, it's not!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738591/560648) **The result, then — regardless of any "register size" — must abide by the rules of the language, yielding the mathematically appropriate answer (256).** And, even if it were, you'd hit that undefined behaviour so the question would be moot.

Under the bonnet, if more than one register is needed to hold a variable, then that's what will and must happen (at whatever performance cost is implied as a result). That's if a register is used *at all*; remember, you're programming in an abstraction, not hand-crafting machine code. The program snippet you showed can be completely optimised away during compilation and doesn't require any runtime instructions *at all*.

Comment: Both `int` and `unsigned int` is guaranteed to be at least 16bits.

Comment: This is mostly right, modulo the above two comments.

Answer (score 2):

> Would the same programm on a system with registers of 8bit length the result be `b=0`?

No.

In the expression `a << 8` the variable `a` will get *promoted* to an `int` before the bit shift. And an `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits.

`b` will have the value 256 on all platforms unless there's a bug in the compiler.

However, if you changed the second line to `uint32 b = a << 16;` you might get strange results. `a` would still get promoted to an `int`, but if `int` is two bytes long, then `a << 16` will invoke undefined behavior.